# JAVA Dynamic Method Reference

Tags: java, methods, dynamic, reference

I have an array of variable;

```
String[] variableArray = {"id","name","address"};
```

Each element of the array are variable names of a class Person.

so to get the value we can use

```
Person::getId; 
Person::getName;
Person::getAddress;
```

Is there any way where i can iterate the array and get the values using method reference..?

```
Arrays.asList(variableArray).forEach(objName -> {
    Person::get 'objName' 
});
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reflection.
Try (If you do it in your way):

```
var clazz=Person.class;
Person thisReference=...;
Arrays.asList(variableArray).forEach(objName -> {
    String cap = objName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + objName.substring(1);
    String property=null;
    try{
       var method=clazz.getDeclaredMethod(getDeclaredMethod);
       property=(String)method.invoke(thisReference);
    } catch(Exception exception){
      //Do something (and maybe split up the exceptions to handle each one different)
    }
    //Do something with property.
});
```

I would do it in this way:

```
var clazz=Person.class;
Person thisReference=...;
//You will have to do error handling.
Method[] methodArray=new Method[]{clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getId"),
                                 clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getName"),
                                 clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getAddress")};
for(Method method:methodArray){
   //Again, error handling...
   String property = (String) method.invoke(thisReference);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use reflection yourself or use a library that encapsulates the reflection part like [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/). If you have a fixed set of properties only and don't aim for a generic solution using a simple mapping might work as well:

```
Person person = new Person(); // you need an instance of person as the getters are not static

String[] variableArray = {"id","name","address"};

Map<String, Supplier<String>> getters = new HashMap<>();
getters.put("id", person::getId);
getters.put("name", person::getName);
getters.put("address", person::getAddress);

Arrays.asList(variableArray).forEach(objName -> {
   String value = getters.get(objName).get();
   // do something with value
});
```

As the getters in `Person` are however not static you will need to have the actual person instance for the method references to work.